# How to kill supervisord if child process exited with non-zero status

Tags: bash, supervisord

I have 3 child proccesses in supervisord, one of them is java.

```
[program:sgw]
command=java -jar test.jar
process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=unexpected        ; when to restart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
exitcodes=1
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=TERM
startsec=0
```

I want to stop the java process when it returns exit-code 1 and supervisord should not restart it, hence **autorestart=unexpected and exitcodes=1**

Now, How do I kill parent process, i.e. supervisord once java is exited. here is my event section.

```
[eventlistener:processes]
command=/bin/bash -c ". /etc/stop-supervisor.sh"
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED, PROCESS_STATE_EXITED, PROCESS_STATE_FATAL, PROCESS_STATE_UNKNOWN, PROCESS_STATE_BACKOFF
```

/etc/stop-supervisord.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "READY\n";

while read line; do
  echo "Processing Event: $line" >&2;
  kill -3 $(cat "/data/logs/supervisord.pid")
done < /dev/stdin
```

I see java is exited but supervisord is still running along with two other processes.